# How to check if last_updated more than 15.minutes.ago?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This should be simple, but I am getting edge cases that seem to be failing, I am doing something wrong and it kinda confuses me. I have a method like this:

```
def self.needs_updating?(last_updated_time, time_since_update)
  return false if last_updated_time.nil?
  time_since_update < last_updated_time
end
```

It's called using this syntax:

```
Tools::Utils.needs_updating?(@entry.updated_at, 15.minutes.ago)
```

What I am trying to do is discover whether @entry has been updated at least 15.minutes.ago. If it has been updated 20.minutes.ago this should return true, if it has been updated 1.minute.ago, it should return false.

I think i may need to insert DateTime.now.utc in there maybe. But how can i do it so that I can keep using the Rails idiom (14.minutes.ago, 1.hour.ago etc..) ?

Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, i think i should maybe use time_since_update > last_updated_time ? I may have mixed the comparison, this one looks like it could do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
def self.needs_updating?(last_updated_time, time_since_update)
  return false if last_updated_time.nil?
  last_updated_time < time_since_update
end
```

If you want time in UTC use `last_updated_time.utc < time_since_update.utc`

If you want time in your local time use `last_updated_time.localtime < time_since_update.localtime`

example

```
last_updated_time = @entry.updated_at
=> 2022-05-11 22:30:11 +0200

time_since_update = 15.minutes.ago
=> 2022-05-12 22:35:15 +0200

last_updated_time < time_since_update
=> true
```